# Converting SQL to LINQ (inner join into a left outer join) C#

Tags: c#, linq, left-join, inner-join

Hi I am trying to convert the below piece of SQL into LINQ (only learning linq so bear with me)

```
SELECT SUM(Bt.Stake)AS TotalStake, SUM(Bt.Payout) AS TotalPayout, SUM(Bt.Stake - Bt.BetPayout) AS TotalProfitLoss, COUNT(Bt.BtID) AS NumberBts,
                      EV_MarketMix.Description
            FROM         Bt INNER JOIN
                                  Slip ON Bt.SlipID = Slip.SlipId LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                  EV_MarketMix ON Bt.MarketMixID = EV_MarketMix.MarketMixID
            WHERE(Slip.DateScanned >= @StartDate) AND(Slip.DateScanned < @EndDate)
            GROUP BY EV_MarketMix.Description
```

I know how to do inner joins ok with the `join  in  on  equals` linq format and ive read of how to do left outer joins using the `DefaultIfEmpty()` property but I am unsure of how to proceed in doing an inner join immediately followed by an left outer join. Can anyone advise me on how to go from there? Any help or pointing me in the right direction to look would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: See sample code at www.msdn.com : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in SQL, you can do an inner join followed by another left join

```
var query = (from t1 in Context.Table1
    join t2 in Context.Table2 on //...  //inner join
    join t3 in Context.Table3 on /*...*/ into joined //left join
    from joined.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new 
    {
       //....
    };
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for! Simple implementation too thanks!